# Is there any way to get Facebook read_stream permission using the latest Facebook app review?

Tags: ios

I am developing Social networking iPhone app in which we have facebook as one of the option. We have to display user's feeds but for that I need `read_stream` permission.

Unfortunately, our app has not been verified. This is message that we’ve received from the Facebook review team:

> This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client. It may only be used to provide people with access to this content.

I am not getting what exactly I have to do to acquire this permission. Is there anyone who has solved the above issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not getting what exactly I have to do to acquire this permission.

There's nothing to get here. The message you've received from the Facebook team indicates that you can't get this permission for an iOS application, because there is already an official Facebook application (a "native client", in their words) available for iOS.