# Facebook user_actions and read_stream permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions

Does anybody know the apps which use user_actions and read_stream permissions? We've been trying to get our app granted, but got replied “read_stream` will only be granted to apps that replicate FB functionality on a platform that doesn't have a native FB client already”. Are there any other ways to solve it? Maybe we need to change the workflow somehow? Thanks for any advice and help!

Comment: there is no way, unless you create an app for a platform without a native fb client. which is most likely not the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get Facebook read\_stream permission using the latest Facebook app review?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948271/is-there-any-way-to-get-facebook-read-stream-permission-using-the-latest-faceboo)

Comment: @luschn I also was wondering if anyone knows apps which use user_actions and read_stream permissions, and I didn't find examples in previous posts.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the `user_actions.*` permissions approved. For `read_stream`, it will be nearly impossible.

But think about whether you really need this, or if maybe `user_status` is enough (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_status).